# Removing the default text in Xceed datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I am using the Codeplex verison of Xceed datagrid.
But while showing the grid in form, 'Powered by Xceed' text is coming in top right of datagrid.
[image]

Is it possible to remove this? How?

Comment: if you use the community edition, this is not legal, it goes against the license agreement (No watermark = Plus ed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this. It worked.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:HierarchicalGroupByControl}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short blog post on this the other day. I made a simple extension method to find the adorner layer and remove it.

```
 public static class XceedDataGridExtensions
 {
   public static void RemoveWaterMark(this DataGridControl grid)
   {
     object hgbc = XceedDataGridExtensions.FindChild<HierarchicalGroupByControl>(grid, null);
     AdornerLayer al = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(hgbc as Control);
     al.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
   }

  static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
  {
     // Confirm parent and childName are valid.
     if (parent == null) return null;
       T foundChild = null;
     int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
     for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
     {
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
       // If the child is not of the request child type child
       T childType = child as T;
       if (childType == null)
       {
         // recursively drill down the tree
         foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
         // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.
         if (foundChild != null) break;
       }
       else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
       {
         var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
         // If the child's name is set for search
         if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
         {
            // if the child's name is of the request name
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // child element found.
         foundChild = (T)child;
         break;
      }
    }

    return foundChild;
   }
 }
```

You can read more about it here: http://blog.itsnotfound.com/2013/02/xceed-community-datagridcontrol-watermark-removal/

Also, @punker76 in my opinion and as is stated in a discussion thread on the community site, the removal of the watermark is not against the MSPL. The devs acknowledged how to remove the watermark using modifications to the source code. They are even working on a more acceptable solution.  Please see the discussion here: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/428413

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simples way to remove the `GroupByControl` is to modify the `FixedHeaders` property:

```
 <xcdg:DataGridControl  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           UpdateSourceTrigger="CellContentChanged"
                           Grid.Row="8"
                           AutoCreateColumns="False"
                           IsDeleteCommandEnabled="True"
                           SelectionMode="Single"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Instructions,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
            <xcdg:TableView ShowRowSelectorPane="False"
                            UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False"
                            ColumnStretchMode="All">
                <xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                                   AllowColumnReorder="False"
                                                   AllowColumnResize="False" />
                            <xcdg:GroupByControl x:Name="groupByControl"
                                                 Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
            </xcdg:TableView>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Title"
                         FieldName="Title" />
            <xcdg:Column Title="Content"
                         FieldName="Content" />
            <xcdg:Column Title="Image Url"
                         FieldName="ImageUrl" />
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Just set value of property `Visibility` to "Collapsed" like in the example.